# listView android clickable in one list and no clickable in other list

Tags: android, mysql, listview, adapter

how to make listView clickable  in one list and not clickable in other list if value is null or empty

```
                ListView lv = getListView();

                if (TAG_UID.isEmpty() && TAG_UID == null)
                {

                    lv.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else 
                {
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem


                                Intent in = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this,
                                        MyActivity2.class);
                                startActivity(in);



                        }

                    });
```

value get from mysql database, thanks for help

Comment: you want all the item in the listview non clickable?

Comment: no, in listView have item clickable and have item no clickable. Item with non clickable because value in database mysql empty. can you help me?thanks

Comment: in my case empty value is TAG_UID (user id)

Comment: `if(value == null)` then `item.setClickable(false);`

Comment: on item.setClickable(false); , what is item?

Answer (score 0):

For the position you want make it non-clickable handle it in this manner using `return` statement

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==2){
                    return;
                }else{
                    //put your code here
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you give me example more detil, sorry iam new be